# C# localization not working in Chinese OS but works on Chinese language pack

Tags: c#, localization, language-packs

I have an application which uses resource files to localize text. The EXE is in a separate project and resources are in separate project. When deployed on English OS with Chinese language pack it works fine, but when deployed on complete Chinese OS it does not show Chinese text. I did a assembly binding logging, and found out that the system looks for zh-cn dll and this dll is successfully found and loaded.

If it queries for the DLL why does it still fall back to English? The only reason it would do this is that it does not find the queried string. Any ideas whats going wrong?

I am using the standard resource files with PublicResXFileCodeGenerator to compile my resources and I am using resource properties to refer to the string, also I am not explicitly passing any culture information.

Comment: Please post the code that handles the localization selection process.  We need to know which operating system exactly.  The behavior with language packs on Windows XP is DIFFERENT then if we are talking about Windows 7 and/or Windows Vista.

Comment: In both the cases I am running on Windows 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved. Here's what had happened. Our build script sets authenticode signing on all DLLs, we had not authenticode signed the zh-cn and ja resource dlls. So looks like .net was not picking up the DLL and defaulting to english.

Comment: Very unlikely explanation, it is not the way Authenticode signing works.  And is completely incompatible with your observation that it *did* load the satellite assembly.